# Rails: Set a Gemfile item for remote server only when running bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I am trying to get this Rails 3.1 app onto Heroku, I am on Win7 64bit and cannot exactly install therubyracer gem, which is, so far from what I can see thru trials, required to not get an error (H10 code) from Heroku.

I already do a

group :production do
 gem 'therubyracer'
end

to try to separate it from development env, but no matter, when I run bundle, it still tries to install therubyracer which throws error as-of-now on Windows.

Is there a way that I can specify that gem in the gemfile but it will be completely ignore on the dev box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try `bundle install --without development` if you want gems specified under `group :development` to be ignored.

Kindly note that this will create a `.bundle` directory which will cause this to persist in the future.  It's best to add this folder to your `.gitignore` if using git; simply remove it if want to remove this persistance.

Comment: Hey that did it. What I wanted though was actually bundle install --without production ---- Thanks for the hint about the .bundle, got that ignored. ---- kind of sucks to have to type the extra each time I do a bundle install, but who am I to complain :).

Comment: You could setup an alias in your ~/.bashrc such as `alias bundle_prod_dis='bundle install --without production'` ?

Comment: maybe powershell, don't have .bashrc :(